# Getting the error "$().once is not a function"

Tags: 7, modal-dialogs

till today noon my site working fine but after that suddenly my site was struck and in error console it give me below error.

> Error: TypeError: $(...).once is not a function Source File: modules/overlay/overlay-child.js?mixmsl on Line: 111.

```
/**
 * Modify forms depending on their relation to the overlay.
 *
 * By default, forms are assumed to keep the flow in the overlay. Thus their
 * action attribute get a ?render=overlay suffix.
 */
Drupal.overlayChild.behaviors.parseForms = function (context, settings) {
  $('form', context).once('overlay', function () {
    // Obtain the action attribute of the form.
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    // Keep internal forms in the overlay.
    if (action == undefined || (action.indexOf('http') != 0 && action.indexOf('https') != 0)) {
      action += (action.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' : '?') + 'render=overlay';
      $(this).attr('action', action);
    }
    // Submit external forms into a new window.
    else {
      $(this).attr('target', '_new');
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Its looking for DRUPAL_ROOT/misc/jquery.once.js, are u sure its in position?


or you can disable the overlay module untill you figure it out..

Comment: yes i have checked in that path and jquery.once.js is there. and when i disable overlay module still it will give error.

Answer (score 5):

The standard `$` alias is not used in Drupal 7, to provide the best possible support for no-conflict jQuery.

You need to wrap your code in a closure like so:

```
(function($) {
  // Add code using $ as an alias for jQuery here...
})(jQuery);
```

See [Managing Javascript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722) for complete examples and explanations.

Comment: or change all your $ to jQuery ...

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {


Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {

/////// Place your code after this


Drupal.behaviors.textarea = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('.form-textarea-wrapper.resizable', context).once('textarea', function () {
      var staticOffset = null;
      var textarea = $(this).addClass('resizable-textarea').find('textarea');
      var grippie = $('<div class="grippie"></div>').mousedown(startDrag);

      grippie.insertAfter(textarea);

      function startDrag(e) {
        staticOffset = textarea.height() - e.pageY;
        textarea.css('opacity', 0.25);
        $(document).mousemove(performDrag).mouseup(endDrag);
        return false;
      }

      function performDrag(e) {
        textarea.height(Math.max(32, staticOffset + e.pageY) + 'px');
        return false;
      }

      function endDrag(e) {
        $(document).unbind('mousemove', performDrag).unbind('mouseup', endDrag);
        textarea.css('opacity', 1);
      }
    });
  }
};

/////// place all your codes after this
  }
};

  })(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

Comment: this did it for me, hope it helps